# Steps to take when finding a decomposition of cubic graphs by Peterson's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

If I had a cubic, bridgeless graph. What steps would I take when trying to show that the Peterson's theorem works for it?

The theorem states that "A cubic bridgeless graph G has a decomposition
into a 1-factor and a 2-factor".

Now if I had to draw it out by hand, how would I go about finding a perfect matching?

I have been taking some small cubic graphs like the Peterson graph and other that have like 12 vertices and 18 edges. But I feel like I am blindly trying out all possible 1-factors, and then trying to form a 2-factor (cycle) from the remaining edges.

I only have knowledge referenced in "Pearls of Graph Theory", but I can not find anything that will help me identify the matchings.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can try to find a "constructive" proof of the theorem.

Comment: If you find a 1-factor, the remaining edges are *guaranteed* to be a 2-factor, in any cubic graph. Each vertex has degree 1 in the 1-factor, so it must have degree 2 in what's left over, making the leftover a 2-factor.